# How to generate increment version number using sendkeys

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium

I am testing a .gov website and I want to add a incrementing version number into my java script. The website cannot have duplicate account title entries or version numbers.

I have searched google and youtube but cannot find anything
the code I am currently using is:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")).sendKeys("e2e01");
```

The code above enters in e2e01 I would like my code to either increase the version number by +1 each time the script is run or generate a random number on the end of e2e to make it go to e2e02 then e2e03 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create an XML file which would act as data provider for your test. In each run it increment the number and update the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vars>
  <counter>1</counter>
</vars>
```

Function to increment the value:

```
int incrementCounter() {
   int counter = loadValueFromXML();
   counter++;
   incrementValueInXML();
}
```

And in you sendKeys:

```
driver.findElement(
By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")).sendKeys("e2e0" + Integer.toString(incrementCounter()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the above would just give me a counter eaach time I run it, is there a way to add the characters e2e before the increments?

Answer (score 1):

Hi This is similar code you can convert in java which I have done in python for your reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import traceback
from builtins import str
from robot.utils.error import Throwable

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:/automation/config/IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/a[1]/i").click()
test=True;
loopCounter=0;
try:
    while (test):
    loopCounter += 1
    if (loopCounter == 20):
        test=False
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#gsc-i-id1").send_keys("e2e" + str(format(loopCounter, '02d')))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#gsc-i-id1").clear()

except :
    Throwable(traceback)
```

Comment: this answer is full of unrelated code that uses bad practices and is written in a different language.  How is that helpful?